# What is the best way to implement customized authorization in MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an MVC5 application. In my application, I have two tables named employee and the department. My question is how can I provide customized authorization at the department and the employee level in MVC?

For example, there is a from to create a new employee. What I want to do is, only the user from human resource department or the user having 'create new employee' rights(it is not mandatory for the user to be from the human resource department), should be able to access the form.

If it was a webpage application, I would be doing something like creating a user rights table having both department id and the employee/user id fields with other fields (like create new employee, view employee list, create new department) for storing their access rights and then check their values for the logged in user while accessing those pages.

As I am new to MVC, I am looking for some suggestions for the best way to implement this. Any good ideas/suggestions are welcome!

Comment: If you're new to MVC as you say why don't you use Membership Schema provided by .NET for Authorization and then make your users' table to have a column id pointing to .net Users' table?

Comment: @Zarana, ASP.Net Membership has been replaced with ASP.Net Identity.

Answer (score 2):

If you used default template for your MVC5 project, you already have most of what you need. The ASP.NET Identity set of features is your entry point. Look into the `IdentityRole` as a base for managing your app's roles, `IdentityUser`, `IdentityUserRole` and `IdentityUserClaim` for your authorization tasks.